# count and add precipitation values of 5 consecutive days or more below 2 mm in R

Tags: r

I have a rainfall time series and would like to know the accumulated amount of rainfall that spanned 5 days or more.

My data are daily observations as shown below.

| Date | Prec |
| --- | --- |
| 1983-01-01 | 1.12 |
| 1983-01-02 | 1.08 |
| 1983-01-03 | 1.11 |
| 1983-01-04 | 2.00 |
| 1983-01-05 | 1.44 |
| 1983-01-06 | 3.12 |
| 1983-01-07 | 0.12 |
| 1983-01-08 | 0.52 |
| 1983-01-09 | 1.62 |
| 1983-01-10 | 0.12 |
| 1983-01-11 | 1.33 |
| 1983-01-12 | 1.14 |
| 1983-01-13 | 1.16 |
| 1983-01-14 | 1.00 |
| 1983-01-15 | 5.12 |
| 1983-01-16 | 6.12 |

I've already got the sum of days by setting a range of days (5 consecutive days), but there is the possibility of having a longer sequence of days that meet my condition.

```
prec <- transform(prec, extreme =+(Prec < 2))
r <- rle(prec$extreme)
r$values[r$values == 1] <- r$lengths[r$values == 1]
prec <- transform(prec, n=unlist(Map(rep, r$values, 
r$lengths)))
```

and the result I hope is this:
[image]

I've already got the sum of days by setting a range of days (5 consecutive days), but there is the possibility of having a longer sequence of days that meet my condition. And I want there to be columns of total consecutive days (Prec < 2), cumulative total of those consecutive days, start date and end date of the sequence.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand the connection between your example data and the desired output in your picture. The values don't match, can you explain the transformation from your data to your output?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the image so that it faithfully represents the data.
The data I put in the table is just a snippet of the data. (to try to reproduce).,

I used the function to count the total of the sequence of days where rainfall was less than 2mm for at least 5 days, but not how I wanted it. because I want you to just write in the last line of the sequence along with the sum value of that sequence and the start and end date of the sequence.

Comment: Use rle with a logical expression. I suspect there are already worked examples in SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

 data %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(Prec > 2)) %>%
  filter(Prec <= 2) %>%  
  summarise(start_date = min(Date),
            end_date = max(Date),
            rain_acc = sum(Prec), 
            days_con = n()) %>% 
  select(-grp)
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  start_date end_date   rain_acc days_con
  <date>     <date>        <dbl>    <int>
1 1983-01-01 1983-01-05     6.75        5
2 1983-01-07 1983-01-14     7.01        8
```

### Data

```r
structure(list(Date = structure(c(4748, 4749, 4750, 4751, 4752, 
4753, 4754, 4755, 4756, 4757, 4758, 4759, 4760, 4761, 4762, 4763
), class = "Date"), Prec = c(1.12, 1.08, 1.11, 2, 1.44, 3.12, 
0.12, 0.52, 1.62, 0.12, 1.33, 1.14, 1.16, 1, 5.12, 6.12)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Date = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_date", 
    "collector")), Prec = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: Sorry for the structure of the question, I'm a novice OS user.
Thank you very much for the replies.

the response was successful, but analyzing the output, some sequences have a day less. I realized that it's always the first sequence of X days.
Ex: 1983-02-01 / 1983-02-05 counts only 4 days, when it would be 5

Another point I wanted to know is whether it is possible to present only sequences >= 5 days. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: You could add `%>% filter(days_con >= 5)` to the code shown above. Regarding your 4 days issue: I don't know, I guess, there are some specialties with your data?